# The sufficient condition in the proof of Lebesgue differentiation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am reading the proof of Lebesgue differentiation theorem in wiki. It said that to prove
$$\lim_{m(B) \rightarrow 0\\x\in B}\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f(y)dy = f(x), $$
it is sufficient to prove that for each $\alpha > 0$
$$E_\alpha=\left\{ x:  \lim \sup_{m(B) \rightarrow 0\\x\in B} \left|\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f(y)dy-f(x)\right|> 2\alpha\right\}$$
has measure zero.

I have no idea why the condition above is sufficient. For me, the equivalent condition would be that
$$E_\alpha=\lim \sup_{m(B) \rightarrow 0\\x\in B} \left\{ x:  \left|\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f(y)dy-f(x)\right|> 2\alpha\right\}$$
has measure zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $m(E_{\alpha})=0$ for every $\alpha >0$  then $m(\cup_n E_{1/n})=0$ and for any $x $ not in $\cup_n E_{1/n}$ we have $\frac 1 {m(B)} \int_{B} f(y)dy \to f(x)$.

The way you have defined $E_{\alpha}$ does not make sense. How do define  $\lim \sup$ of a continuum of sets and why is it measurable?

Comment: Many thanks for your anwser, I may abuse the definition of lim sup. In your statement, is the following fact used?For fixed $x$, $\lim \sup \left|\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f(y)dy-f(x)\right| < 1/n, \forall n$ implies $\lim \sup \left|\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f(y)dy-f(x)\right|  = 0$, thus, $\lim  \left|\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f(y)dy-f(x)\right| = 0$.

Comment: @ZHANGWei That is exactly the argument.